# openlayers error on draw/modify (in vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, openlayers, openlayers-3

[The code I am using is in my previous question (resolved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302662/openlayers-map-not-showing-in-vuejs)

The interaction works perfectly and my goal is to get an array of coordinates, also works perfectly. Although everything works, I am getting an error in console every time I move the mouse in the display area. It doesn't affect functioning, but obviously I need to solve it... any ideas?

```
Draw.js?ac29:579 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getGeometry' of null
    at Draw.modifyDrawing_ (Draw.js?ac29:579)
    at Draw.handlePointerMove_ (Draw.js?ac29:479)
    at Draw.handleEvent (Draw.js?ac29:871)
    at Map.handleMapBrowserEvent (PluggableMap.js?fe37:924)
    at MapBrowserEventHandler.boundListener (events.js?1e8d:41)
    at MapBrowserEventHandler.dispatchEvent (Target.js?0ec0:101)
    at MapBrowserEventHandler.handlePointerMove_ (MapBrowserEventHandler.js?2ad6:260)
    at PointerEventHandler.boundListener (events.js?1e8d:41)
    at PointerEventHandler.dispatchEvent (Target.js?0ec0:101)
    at PointerEventHandler.fireNativeEvent (PointerEventHandler.js?b114:397)
```

Comment: Where did you use *getGeometry()* in your current code, to begin with? In your previous question all of these methods were commented. That's pretty obvious you try to get the geometry of some _undefined_ object somewhere.

Comment: Actually, I don't see it in current code at all. So I wondered if it was being tracked by mouse location, or something, or if because it is vuejs the variable needed to be exported in the data object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying something quite random, but you maybe want to add some condition in you current code:

```
var modify = new Modify({source: source});
modify.on('modifyend',function(e){
   if(e.features && e.features.getArray().length) { //add this line
      console.log("feature id is",e.features.getArray()[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0]);
   }
});
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, I have to say this project has shown me I need to bump up my skills in this area quite a bit, I had 2 such errors in the project. Whats odd is without vuejs there was no such error, and it all worked, I literally copy/pasted from my vanilla js code into these methods :)